# Unable to render 3D plots in Mathematica on Raspberry Pi

Tags: plotting, raspberry-pi, rendering

I just bought a Raspberry Pi 2 and I've just started to use Wolfram Mathematica. I tried to execute one of the examples given in the Wolfram documentations page. The problem that I am facing is that whenever I execute the line of code, I get only the axes(x,y,z) and not the actual 3D plot. Any solutions?

Thank you in advance.

```
Plot3D[Sin[xy], {x,0,3}, {y,0,3}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None]
```

Comment: Sounds like Mathematica can't output graphics to your monitor for some reason. I'm not aware of the Pi's limitations but try `Export["myplot.png",Plot3D[Sin[xy], {x,0,3}, {y,0,3}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> None]]` in the meantime.

Comment: the png file has only the axes and no 3d plot.

Comment: $DisplayFunction returns "Identity"

Comment: by the way, i'm using a samsung led tv as display

Answer (score 2):

It should be Sin[x y], not Sin[xy].
That should solve your problem

Comment: Boom!!! Thanks bro!

Comment: Why not `Sin[x*y]`? I still use * between the parameters!